# Internet Explorer proxy pac files

Tags: windows-7, proxy, pac, internet-explorer-10

We have a simple pac file used for staff in work and at home:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
    /* Exclude "Portico" URL */
    if (shExpMatch(url, "*google.com*"))
    {
        return "DIRECT";
    }
    /* Set proxy? */
    if (isResolvable(host))
    {
        return "PROXY xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080";
    }
    /* Return "DIRECT" if above statements are NOT true */
    return "DIRECT";
}**
```

The file works in work but not at home: we're having to remove the 'use pac file' option from within IE to get their home wifi to work.
Does anyone have any ideas on what I'm doing wrong please? Everything looks ok but it's not working!

Comment: What is the error message shown when usin this at home?

Comment: "cannot find proxy server"

Comment: Well, is your proxy available from anyone on the internet on port 8080?

Comment: never mind - it's fixed now. changed return "PROXY xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080"; to return "PROXY xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080; DIRECT";